# iOS Align a UIView parallel to X-Z plane

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiview, core-animation, transform

I realize that by default a `UIView` is parallel to the X-Y plane, the Z-axis coming straight at you.

How do I rotate this `UIView` so that it is parallel to X-Z plane? I think I have to use `CATransform3D` but am not sure what angle I should give it? M_PI_2 or -M_PI_2 ?

Anybody has any idea? Thanks for help...

**EDIT:** I know that by doing this, the `UIView` will not be visible to the user, but I want to set a particular `UIView` this way & then do some rotation animation on it. So this is what I want..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WHat you probably want to do is to apply a transformation to the view's backing layer. The `transform` property on `UIView` is an affine transformation, not allowing any 3D manipulation. But accessing `view.layer.transform` you have a full 4x4 matrix for your transformation needs, allowing nice funky 3d stuff.

1. Add `QuartzCore.framework` to your target.
2. Import `<QuartzCore/QuartzCore.h>` to get access to the `CALayer` API.
3. Code away.

For example:

```
// Rotate 1/4 by the Y-axis.
myView.layer.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(M_PI_2, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: yes, I kind of thought that this is how I would have to approach, but could you be kind enough to provide some code sample(s)?

Comment: Cool! Also, what's the difference between `CATransform3DMakeRotation` & `CATransform3DRotate` ? I mean both seem to be present for the same purpose right? then why 2 methods?

Comment: `CATransformMakeRotation` makes a rotation fromt he identity matrix. Whereas `CATransform3DRotate` concatenates a rotation on a transformation matrix you already have *(In cases where you want say first rotation and then scaling, etc.)*.